# Multiple submits in ajax form

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have an asp.net core application in which I want to create an ajax form with 2 submit buttons. When I remove the ajax attributes from the form everything works as expected and a request is send to the right action. But when the form is ajax the formaction in the button is ignored and a request is send only to the action specified in the form tag. Here is the form:

```
   <form asp-action="Create"
                  data-ajax="true"
                  data-ajax_method="POST"
                  data-ajax_mode="replace"
                  data-ajax-update="#ajax-update-replace">
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                @Html.ValidationSummary(string.Empty, new { @class = "text-danger" })
                @*REPLACED DIV*@
                <div id="ajax-update-replace"></div>
            </form>
```

These are the buttons in my partial view:

```
  <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                <button type="submit" asp-action="@Url.Action(nameof(QuestionsController.AddAnswerToQuestion))" class="btn btn-default">Add Answer</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

How should I make this work with ajax form ?

Comment: Don't use ajax form (its not even supported any more). Use the jquery `$.ajax()` methods which give you far more flexibility.